# Elementary proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{p_i}) = 0$

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is there an elementary proof that for primes $p_i$,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)=0\;?$$

This follows from [Mertens third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#Mertens%27_third_theorem_and_sieve_theory) which states that

$$ \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right) \sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log{n}} $$

but I was hoping for a self contained proof.

Comment: it is the same as $\sum 1/p_i=\infty$

Comment: You recently asked a question about $y$-smooth numbers which I thought was good. Right as I was about to submit my answer, you deleted it. Why?

Comment: @MiloMoses it had bad typos which I didn’t have time to fix. I will repost today. Thank you for any answer!

Comment: @user8268 Is there an elementary proof of that or do we need to prove Bertrand’s postulate?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Simd The only context in this question is a link.

Comment: @Peter  Ah ok. I can add more about that.

Answer (score 5):

As indicated in a comment, this is as elementary to show as $\sum 1/p = \infty$.

For all real numbers $x$ we have $e^x \geq 1+x$ (note $y = 1+x$ is the tangent line to $y = e^x$ at $(0,1)$), so $\boxed{e^{-1/p} \geq 1 - 1/p}$. Therefore
$$
0 < \prod_{p \leq t} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) \leq e^{-\sum_{p \leq t} 1/p}.
$$
So as soon as you know that $\sum_{p \leq t} 1/p \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$, you know the right side of the displayed inequality above tends o $0$ as $t \to \infty$, so $\prod_{p \leq t} (1-1/p) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: To complete this we seem to need a proof that $\sum  \frac{1}{p_i}$ diverges but this relies on Bertrand’s postulate?

Comment: It doesn't have to use Betrand's postulate, as there are several ways to explain divergence of $\sum 1/p$. None of those arguments is going to be just 2 or 3 lines long. My point was simply that the limit you want is a very easy corollary of divergence of $\sum 1/p$.  So now just focus on finding a proof that $\sum 1/p = \infty$. The standard method is to obtain it from (i) showing $\log \zeta(s) \to \infty$ as $s \to 1^+$ and (ii) showing $\log \zeta(s) = \sum 1/p^s + O(1)$ as $s \to 1^+$.  Whether proofs of (i) and (ii) are short depends on what the audience knows about the zeta-function.